# Adding mini cesium container on Main cesium Container

Tags: cesiumjs

Is it possible to add a mini cesium container on top of Main cesium container as follows [image].

Both containers should render different information. How this can be achieved in cesium?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, but beware that it is a full separate instance of Cesium.  This means it takes its own texture memory, GL context, etc.  Click "Run code snippet" at the bottom of this for an example.

```js
var mainViewer = new Cesium.Viewer('mainCesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false, animation: false, timeline: false
});

var insetViewer = new Cesium.Viewer('insetCesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false, animation: false, timeline: false,
    geocoder: false, baseLayerPicker: false, sceneModePicker: false
});

// Make the inset window display in 2D, to show it's different.
insetViewer.scene.morphTo2D(0);
```

```css
html, body, #mainCesiumContainer {
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#insetCesiumContainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1%;
    right: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.16/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.16/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="mainCesiumContainer"></div>
<div id="insetCesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: You can find an example: https://github.com/knreise/cesium-minimap. But at the end, this implementation uses the solution suggested in the above example.